# can not read luna16 .mhd image file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How I can read images .mhd with python?

The following code

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = sitk.ReadImage("D:/luna16/subset0/1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.100684836163890911914061745866.mhd")
plt.imshow(img)
sitk.WriteImage(img, "D:/luna16/subset0/allnii/output1.nii.gz")`
```

results with error

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageFileReader_Execute: D:\a\1\sitk-build\ITK\Modules\IO\Meta\src\itkMetaImageIO.cxx:488:
ITK ERROR: MetaImageIO(0000026640240250): File cannot be read: D:/luna16/subset0/1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.100684836163890911914061745866.mhd for reading.
Reason: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like the file doesn't exist.  The MetaIO file reader is not seeing the file.